# FirebaseMessagingService does not work when the application is closed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I inherited a class from `FirebaseMessagingService` and added the meta data and service to the manifest, but I have a problem that this class is only triggered when the application is running. Is there any way to make it work even when the application is closed?

```
<application>
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_favicon" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/red" />

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
</application>
```

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        if (notification != null) {
            sendNotification(notification, data);
        }
    } 
private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, Map<String, String> data) {
        Log.d("MyFirebaseMessagingService", notification.getChannelId()+"");
}
}
```

P.s.: I need this to implement the silent mode and some additional actions when a notification is clicked.

Comment: You probably need to set android:exported="true" in your manifest.